# What is "spiral binding machine" called in Russian language?

Tags: перевод

What is "[spiral binding machine](https://www.google.com.ua/search?biw=1366&bih=662&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=spiral%20binding%20machine&oq=spiral%20binding%20ma&gs_l=psy-ab.1.0.0i67k1j0l2j0i67k1j0l6.126808.126972.0.129070.2.2.0.0.0.0.158.288.0j2.2.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.2.285....0.ACR--zy8iVA)" called in Russian language?

*n.b. it is also known as "comb binding machine".

I've been searching googling and I didn't find answer. My purpose is to find the translation in order to find one in Ukrainian web-store which sells it.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are 3 options:

1. Переплетная машина
2. брошюровщик
3. переплетчик